# Python pip doesnt download/install source code from self-made package

Tags: python, python-packaging

Latelly, I've been worked on a Python Package, for learning purposes. I called this package **Logmaster** and, as it suggests, is a logging library. When I install the package (`pip install logmaster`), Only the dist-infos (in this case **logmaster-1.0.1.dist-infos**) are downloaded, not the actual source code.

Project structure:

```
Logmaster
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── logger.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

I tried to decompress the source code of the build (**logmaster-0.1.0**) to see if it was included, which it was, and to modify the content of the `__init__.py`  file from `from .logger import *` to `from . import *`, and it didn't worked.

All the code is on [github](https://github.com/W1L7dev/Logmaster/)

Package on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/logmaster/)

Comment: have you read the python basic packaging guidlines? https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/

Comment: Project directory structure is not a correct `src` layout. I recommend you check this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), pay close attention to the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler solution, use a setup.py. (I changed the directory structure slightly):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/W1L7dev/Logmaster.git
$ cd Logmaster/
$ mv src/ logmaster/
$ echo "" > logmaster/__init__.py
$ rm pyproject.toml
$ rm setup.cfg
$ cat setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='logmaster',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='A simple logging library for Python',
    url='https://github.com/W1L7dev/logmaster',
    author='W1L7dev',
    author_email='w1l7dev@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['logmaster'],
    install_requires=[],
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
)
```

With this it works as expected:

```
$ pip install -e .
Successfully installed logmaster-0.1.0
$ python
>>> from logmaster.logger import Logger
>>> Logger
<class 'logmaster.logger.Logger'>
>>> exit()
$ python3 -m build
Successfully built logmaster-0.1.0.tar.gz and logmaster-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
$ ls dist/
logmaster-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl  logmaster-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was recommended to use a setup.cfg file, and it worked fine. But your answer was useful